# Floated element width affects centering of other

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, margin, centering

Good day to you all,
So i got this problem. I have header and inside there is logo and wrapper with button. I have used margin: 0 auto; to center  wrapper with button and than used flex to center buttons inside wrapper, but now when i am changing logo width (width, font-size, padding etc.) it's actually moving wrapper with buttons out of center of header. How can i make my wrapper always on center of header and ignore width of logo?

Here is what i mean:
[Centering is relative to (width of header)-(width of logo) not just width of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9scKm.png)

Here is my fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zgf0xajq/1/

```
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}
#header{width:100%;height:50px;background-color:blue;}
#logo{float:left;padding:5px 4px;font-size:200%;width:400px;}
#buttonWrapper{background-color:grey;margin:0 auto;width:300px;height:100%;
      display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
      display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
      display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
      display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;}
.tButton{float:left;padding:0 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `#logo {position: absolute}`. But of course this will only work if there is enough space on the left side for the logo. Otherwise #buttonWrapper and #logo will overlay

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i needed.